# $http angularjs POST don't send my data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

my angularjs `$http`

```
userId = '1';

$http({
url: "php/loadTab.php",
method: "POST",
data: userId
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
});
```

heck, POST doesn't send the data to my php. I do echo $_POST['userId'] it returned undefined index. I also tried `data:'userId':'1'`

Comment: Did you try `data:{'userId':'1'}` ?

Comment: @SubirKumarSao yes, not working

Comment: `$http` sends data as JSON, that's why there is nothing in PHP's `$_POST`. There numerous similar questions here on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS | How to Send the Data of Json to database in Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609159/angularjs-how-to-send-the-data-of-json-to-database-in-codeigniter)

Comment: I know it's got a CodeIgniter tag but it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Angular sends the data as JSON, not form encoded key/value pairs so you can set `data` to an object. You almost have it on your second try but you need to include the curly braces, which define an object:

```
data: { 'userId' : userId }
```

Now, on the PHP side you need to access the raw POST data to decode the JSON like so:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo $data->userId;
```

Comment: I seem still don't pass the data. still got the same error.

Comment: Did you try it and it worked ? Because last time I checked, `$http` would by default send data as JSON, so nothing would be found in PHP's `$_POST` variable.

Comment: @ExpertSystem so? just now I use params:{'userId','1'} and it worked but it's $_GET; I need $_POST

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: @user3522457 see updated answer. ExpertSystem is correct about the JSON, so you need to access it in a different way on the PHP side.